# same height of numbers and letters in an index place

Tags: indexing, mathdesign

How create same height of a number (zero) and a letter (e) in an index place?

**Example of the case**

the code:

```
T_{e,0}
```

the wrong **output** of a different height in the indexing between **e** and **0**:

[image]

Comment: they are the same size font as you would see if you just wrote e,0 in normal text, 0 is taller than e just as E is taller than e, are you sure you want to change this?

Comment: Numbers (digits) in math are all the same height, while letters are taller or shorter as in ordinary text.  What you are asking is for a "style" that is not usual.  If the expression were `$T_{b,0}$`, the two subscripts *would* be the same height.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes I do.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, agree about (b,0) but in the case of {e,0} it looks different height.

Comment: what height do you want it to be? in `T_{e,0} + T_{f,0} + T_{1,0}`  do you want all the 0 to be the same size or resized in each case to match the adjacent letter?

Comment: If the expression were `$T_{b,e}$`, would you want the `b` and `e` to be the same height?